# What's wrong with my bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, md5sum

**Suppose to do**:

list duplicate file name per-line accroding same md5sum in current directory

**First install the environment:**

`echo "hello" > file1; cp file1 file2; cp file2 file3;`

**Shell script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#FileName: ls_duplicate.sh

## ls file in size-desc order and long listing format and long-iso timestyle
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 6 2017-11-21 13:58 file1
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 6 2017-11-21 13:58 file2
## -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5 2017-11-21 13:58 output
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \; | xargs ls -lS --time-style=long-iso | awk 'BEGIN { 
getline;getline;
prev_name=$8; prev_size=$5;
}

{
cur_name=$8;
cur_size=$5;

if (prev_size==cur_size)
{
    "md5sum " prev_name | getline;
    prev_md5_sum=$1;

    "md5sum " cur_name | getline;
    cur_md5_sum=$1;

    # print(prev_name, prev_md5_sum, cur_name, cur_md5_sum);  # debug

    ##if the two file is same size and same md5sum, then print duplicate file-name
    if ( prev_md5_sum==cur_md5_sum ) { print prev_name; print cur_name;} 
}

prev_size=cur_size; prev_name=cur_name;
}' | sort -u
```

**Files in Current direcotry**:

`file1 file2 file3 ls_duplicate.sh`

**Run script**:
`./ls_duplicate.sh`

**Output:**

```
file1 b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184 file2 b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184
file2 -rw-rw-r-- file3 b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184
```

so what's happen here `-rw-rw-r--`?

### Solution

well, i solve this myself, instead of using

```
"md5sum " prev_name | getline;
prev_md5_sum=$1;
"md5sum " cur_name | getline;
cur_md5_sum=$1;
```

using instead

```
"md5sum " prev_name | getline md5_sum;
split(md5_sum, arr, "  ");
prev_md5_sum=arr[1];

"md5sum " cur_name | getline md5_sum;
split(md5_sum, arr, "  ");
cur_md5_sum=arr[1];
```

**Note**: you need to change this in script(the original script **did** not work).

Comment: When throwing code at us, please do explain what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Seems like your Bash is fine - it's your AWK that has a problem.

Comment: The edit didn't help; the problem is still unclear. I'd recommend you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us and you understand the problem better.

Comment: Am I right you're trying to emulate what `diff -qs file[12]` does? Of course this can only test two files at once, but so does your script – and as it's currently written it doesn't do `diff -qs file[13]`.

Comment: `md5sum * | sort | awk '{printf ($1==a)?$2" ":"\n"$0" ";a=$1}END{printf "\n"}'` outputs the MD5 hash sum and the corresponding file names, one line per hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you:

- get a list of files
- then their sizes, etc.
- then generate md5sums of files of the same size
- and of those, print the ones with the same md5sum

I'm not going to try and fix the awk code. Instead, note that you're replicating the functionality of the `fdupes` command. From [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/fdupes.1.html):

```
Searches  the  given  path for duplicate files. Such files are found by
comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures,  followed  by  a  byte-by-byte
comparison.
```

I'd strongly suggest you use it instead of writing complex scripts for this.

Failing that, eliminating the size check makes it much easier to find duplicates:

```
$ md5sum * | sort -k1,1 | uniq -w32 -D
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  file1
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  file2
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  file3
```

All hashes from `md5sums` have a width of 32 characters, so it's easy to tell print `uniq` to only compare those 32 characters and print all duplicates found.

If you absolutely must have a size check, then it becomes rather complex, but still simpler than your script. `find` can print file sizes, so there's no need to bring `ls` into the mix:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s/%P\n" | 
  awk -F/ '       # Use / as delimiter, it wont appear in filename
  s[$1]++ {       # if the file size has appeared before
    if (n[$1]) {  # if the first name hasnt been printed yet
      print n[$1] # print it and delete it
      n[$1] = "";
    }
    print $2;     # print filename with duplicated size
    next
  } {n[$1] = $2}  # save filename for each new size encountered'
```

This awk command will print all files whose sizes have been duplicated.

Now, just use the `md5sum | sort | uniq` pipeline mentioned earlier:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s/%P\n" | 
  awk -F/ 's[$1]++ {if (n[$1]){print n[$1]} print $2; n[$1] = ""; next} {n[$1] = $2}' |
  xargs -d '\n' md5sum |
  sort -k1,1 |
  uniq -w32 -D
```

Comment: i never notice the magical powerful function combo like this, i take this code from book `Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook, 2nd Edition` for exercise. From your explanatory explanation and demonstration, i have learned a lot, thanks for you effort. :))